# WITH in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, common-table-expression

Does BigQuery support the `WITH` clause? I don't like formatting too many subqueries.

For example:

```
WITH alias_1 AS (SELECT foo1 c FROM bar)
, alias_2 AS (SELECT foo2 c FROM bar a, alias_1 b WHERE b.c = a.c)
SELECT * FROM alias_2 a;
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Recently introduced BigQuery Standard SQL does support WITH clause
See more about [WITH clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/query-syntax#with-clause)

See also how to [Enabling Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql)

Answer (score 12):

BigQery Standard SQL is supporting `WITH` clause. The syntax is as shown below

```
with table2 as (Select column1,column2 from table1)
    select column1 from table2
```