# Can anyone tell me how I should correct my query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I keep getting an error message for the query below. I am not sure what the problem may be, so any help is appreciated. Also this is the error message I keep getting. Thanks

> Syntax error: Expected keyword AS but got "(" at [1:15]

```sql
WITH PopvsVac (continent, location, date, population, new_vaccinations, RollingPeopleVaccinated) AS 
    (SELECT dea.continent,
         dea.location,
         dea.date,
         dea.population,
         vac.new_vaccinations,
         SUM(CONVERT(int, vac.new_vaccinations)) OVER (PARTITION BY dea.location
    ORDER BY  dea.location,dea.date) AS RollingPeopleVaccinated
    FROM `phonic-scheme-348721.covid_deaths.deaths` dea
    JOIN `phonic-scheme-348721.covid_vaccine.vaccine` vac
        ON dea.location = vac.location
            AND dea.date = vac.date
    WHERE dea.continent is NOT NULL )
SELECT *
FROM PopvsVac
```

Comment: Try again after removing `(continent, location, date, population, new_vaccinations, RollingPeopleVaccinated)` in 1st line.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of WITH clause: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause

Sample:
with test as (select 1 as col1) select * from test

As jaytiger mentioned in comment, you have extra things added into your WITH clause. I can not run your query, but just removing those extra things should work.

Comment: I am watching a video and following along. He has it written exactly like mine and it's going through for him but not me

Comment: If its not in official documentation it's not going to work. Just remove: "(continent, location, date, population, new_vaccinations, RollingPeopleVaccinated)" this whole thing from your query and it will work (assuming rest of the tables/query is correct for which we users have no access to.).

Answer (score 0):

Please try below.

```
WITH
PopvsVac AS (
    SELECT
        dea.continent,
        dea.location,
        dea.date,
        dea.population,
        vac.new_vaccinations,
        SUM(CONVERT(int, vac.new_vaccinations)) OVER (
            PARTITION BY dea.location ORDER BY  dea.location,dea.date
        ) AS RollingPeopleVaccinated
    FROM `phonic-scheme-348721.covid_deaths.deaths` dea
    JOIN `phonic-scheme-348721.covid_vaccine.vaccine` vac
        ON dea.location = vac.location AND dea.date = vac.date
    WHERE dea.continent is NOT NULL
)
SELECT *
FROM PopvsVac
;
```

Syntax

> query_expr:
> [ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] { non_recursive_cte | recursive_cte }[, ...] ]
> { select | ( query_expr ) | set_operation }
> [ ORDER BY expression [{ ASC | DESC }] [, ...] ]
> [ LIMIT count [ OFFSET skip_rows ] ]

Please check the below references for more information:
[1] [Syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause)
[2] [Standard SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37423022/with-in-bigquery)